# PyTorch Linear MINST model training error

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mnist

I am creating a binary classifier based on the MINST dataset using PyTorch. I want my classifier to classify between only 0s and 1s, however, when I train it, the error doesn't decrease and the loss becomes negative.
Here's the error and loss at the first few iterations:

[image]

I was obviously expecting better results.

Here is the code I am using:

```
# Loading the MNISR data reduced to  the 0/1 examples

from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

mnist_train = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
mnist_test = datasets.MNIST("./data", train=False, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_idx = mnist_train.train_labels <= 1
try:
    mnist_train.train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
except AttributeError:
    mnist_train._train_data = mnist_train.train_data[train_idx]
try:
    mnist_train.train_labels = mnist_train.train_labels[train_idx]
except AttributeError:
    mnist_train._train_labels = mnist_train.train_labels[train_idx]

test_idx = mnist_test.test_labels <= 1
try:
    mnist_test.test_data = mnist_test.test_data[test_idx]
except AttributeError:
    mnist_test._test_data = mnist_test.test_data[test_idx]
try:
    mnist_test.test_labels = mnist_test.test_labels[test_idx]
except AttributeError:
    mnist_test._test_labels = mnist_test.test_labels[test_idx]
        
train_loader = DataLoader(mnist_train, batch_size = 100, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(mnist_test, batch_size = 100, shuffle=False)


# Creating a simple linear classifier

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

# do a single pass over the data
def epoch(loader, model, opt=None):
    total_loss, total_err = 0.,0.
    for X,y in loader:
        yp = model(X.view(X.shape[0], -1))[:,0]
        loss = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()(yp, y.float())
        if opt:
            opt.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
        
        total_err += ((yp > 0) * (y==0) + (yp < 0) * (y==1)).sum().item()
        total_loss += loss.item() * X.shape[0]
    return total_err / len(loader.dataset), total_loss / len(loader.dataset)


model = nn.Linear(784, 1)
opt = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1)
print("Train Err", "Train Loss", "Test Err", "Test Loss", sep="\t")
for i in range(10):
    train_err, train_loss = epoch(train_loader, model, opt)
    test_err, test_loss = epoch(test_loader, model)
    print(*("{:.6f}".format(i) for i in (train_err, train_loss, test_err, test_loss)), sep="\t")
```

I don't know why my error does not decrease nor why my loss keeps getting more negative. Does anyone spot the error?

Comment: can you post the shape of your x_train and y_train. I think it is something wrong with the shape

Comment: These are the shapes :X shape:  torch.Size([1000, 1, 28, 28]), 
y shape:  torch.Size([1000])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. My initial code to select only 1s and 0s from the MNIST dataset didn't work. So obviously, applying BCELoss to a non-binary dataset was making the model fail.

Answer (score 0):

As mnist data consists of 10 different outputs change the model to output size to 10

```
model = nn.Linear(784, 10)
```

Also change the loss to cross entropy loss and reduce the learning rate to some smaller value(0.001) and use much deeper model.

Probably the above changes should solve your problem

Comment: But I am only trying to classify between 0s and 1s, hence I made my output size 1. I already tried playing with the learning rate and it didn't solve it. My main question is why the loss is negative since, by definition, it cannot be.